# How can I send the selected information in an html page(JSP) to a servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send a query to a database using a servlet(ExportDB.java). I am trying to send the data from the dropdown list to the servlet. This is the form that contains the list.

```
<form>
    <select name="day">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        ...
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select name="month">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        ...
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        ...
        <option value="2029">2029</option>
        <option value="2030">2030</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Export" onclick="exportDB()"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function exportDB() {
        window.open('ExportDB');
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

This is the line of code from ExportDB.java that is causing the issues (NullPointerException)

```
sqlite4java.export(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("day")), Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("month")), Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year")));
```

This is where I believe my mistake lies. I cant quite figure out how I link the information to the servlet. How can I do this so that it works? and also why isnt my current way working?

Comment: Have you tried adding `id` attribute to your `select` ?

Comment: @PradeepSimha I did and received the same error

Comment: `<select>` isn't a combobox. It's a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<form action="ExportDB" target="_blank">
<select name="day">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    ...
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="month">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    ...
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    ...
    <option value="2029">2029</option>
    <option value="2030">2030</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Export" />
</form>
```

You should also add the method you are using in your ExportDB servlet.
If you are using the post method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
int year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year"));
...
}
```

You should add method="post" to your form

```
<form action="ExportDB" target="_blank" method="POST">
```

Same goes for GET

Comment: No problem! Check the edit about the post & get methods aswell, it might help you when you are having problems with forms later on

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="..." method="POST">

if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
    String dayParam = request.getParameter("day");
    ...

    try {
        int day = Integer.parseInt(dayParam, 10);
        ...
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        log.error(...); ...
    }
    if (form data okay) {
       response.sendRedirect(...);
       return;
    }
}
```

I cannot see much wrong, action and method were missing; *there must be (using web.xml) an url-pattern which catches the action URL.* You could distinguish between GET (display the form) and POST (receive the results.